# Failed to set DO connection string in Nested Edge scenario while starting device update agent

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-identity, azure-iot-hub-device-update

I've installed azure identity service on my Ubuntu 18.04 and pasted primary connection string on config.toml. After that I've installed azure device update agent (cloned repo and followed this: https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/blob/main/docs/agent-reference/how-to-build-agent-code.md) and configured in du-config.json connection type as AIS and cleaned connection string data.

Now, once trying to start device update agent, I get this message:

```
[E] Failed to set DO connection string in Nested Edge scenario, result: 0x00000000 [StartupAgent]
[I] Agent exited with code 1 [main]
[I] Agent is shutting down with signal 0. [ShutdownAgent]
[I] De-initializing command listener thread [UninitializeCommandListenerThread]
[I] ADUC agent stopping [AzureDeviceUpdateCoreInterface_Destroy]
[I] Calling ADUC_Unregister [ADUC_MethodCall_Unregister]
```

followed by:

```
deviceupdate-agent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

This page: https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/issues/209 says that a dependency (do-client) is not creating the directory "/etc/deliveryoptimization-agent" after it's installation (I've installed dependences by: `./scripts/install-deps.sh -a`), so I tried creating that dir by my own:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/deliveryoptimization-agent
sudo chgrp -R do /etc/deliveryoptimization-agent
sudo chown do:do /etc/deliveryoptimization-agent
sudo chmod 0750 /etc/deliveryoptimization-agent
```

But even so I still get the same error. Unfortunately there is no other clue on which is the issue.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: I could make it to work by creating a new ubuntu VM, doing the same until "./scripts/install-deps.sh -a", when then I cloned and installed do-client manually (although install-deps.sh -a supposed to do it all), and finally installed device update agent (by deb package).

Comment: Hi Gustavo, please post your work around as an answer and mark it as Accepted Answer. It might help other community members who run into similar issue identify a way to get past this issue.

Comment: I don't think my workaround should be the accepted answer. This was a POC on a specific and controlled environment. As I'll be developing for production, I'm expecting to find this kind of issues again and I'd like to have a solution. Unfortunately device update agent does not provide enough and detailed information for it's errors.